# How to add button control in gmap.net wpf control?

Tags: c#, google-maps, gmap.net

Gmap.net wpf control has markers as item source. any idea how to add button control to it. i.e. transparent zoom in and out button?

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to position the respective buttons above the map control, and use them to control the parameters of the map control.

**Edit:** I wouldn't try to include buttons to the control itself, easiest thing to do in WPF is to place custom `UIContol`s as buttons on a layer above the map control, e.g. within a `Grid` layout. And then simply have button commands trigger the desired map functionalities such as zoom etc. Need a sample to get an idea? Or is my suggestion way from what you try to achieve?

Comment: how do I set the position? is it something like absolute positioning in css?

Comment: Thanks. But I want the buttons above the map. i.e. semi transparent buttons.

Comment: Which is perfectly possible with a `Grid` layout, just a matter of order, add the map control to the XAML first, then the buttons.

Comment: Thanks mate! can you give me an example? I have tried to do this way but when I put the button after map I don't know how to move the button up in the map. it displays underneath. also the map then requires explicit height. any way to stretch it to full width?

Comment: If you can, use the `Grid` layout for this and look for some samples using Grid columns and properties  `HorizontalAlignment` and/or `VerticalAlignment`.